# PowerShell "echo on"

Tags: powershell, debugging, command, echo, script-debugging

This is a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/102098/powershell-script-showing-commands-run.  I thought it would be more appropriate to ask this question here.

I am playing around with PowerShell scripts and they're working great. However, I am wondering if there is any way to also show all the commands that were run, just as if you were manually typing them in yourself. This would be similar to "echo on" in batch files. I looked at the PowerShell command-line arguments, the cmdlets, but I didn't find anything obvious.

Comment: I am a programmer, and I love PowerShell, but I think this is a non-programming question, and belongs on  ServerFault.

Comment: I am a programmer and I love PowerShell and I think this question is right at home at stackoverflow. I use PowerShell as part of my programming toolkit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start-Transcript doesn't catch any exe output.  That's a show stopper for me.  I hate to say it but the best way I've found to do this is:

```
cmd /c powershell.exe -file c:\users\hillr\foo.ps1 > foo.log
```

This captures everything AFAICT.

Comment: The problem is you have to sprinkle this all over your script, wherever you call an EXE.  And if you invoke someone else's script that calls an EXE, you have to modify their script. So yeah, not ideal.  :-)

Comment: Ah, Andy's link probably explains why I wasn't seeing much with start-transcript.  I'll play around with it some more tomorrow, along with Keith's idea (and Richard's below).

Comment: [**updated link from 1st comment**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/workaround-for-start-transcript-on-native-processes/) And this is what's in that article: `Start-Transcript; 
ipconfig | Out-Default; 
Stop-Transcript`

Comment: But this will not include error stream, for that: `...2>&1 >> file.log`

Answer (score 94):

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
```

- 0: Turn script tracing off.
- 1: Trace script lines as they run.
- 2: Trace script lines, variable
  assignments, function calls, and scripts.

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug?view=powershell-6

Comment: Adding an article that explains this more and gives examples, for posterity's viewing pleasure: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/tracing-the-execution-of-a-powershell-script/

Comment: This does not show *"all the commands that were run"*. Actually no commands are shown at all.

Comment: Useful, but unfortunately, it doesn't expand variables like bash `set -x` does.

Answer (score 4):

I added -verbose to desired commands. E.g.

```
Copy-Item c:\xxx d:\xxx -verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\workspaces\silverlight> start-transcript -?

NAME
    Start-Transcript
    
SYNOPSIS
    Creates a record of all or part of a Windows PowerShell session in a text file.
    
    
SYNTAX
    Start-Transcript [[-Path] <string>] [-Append] [-Force] [-NoClobber] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
    
    
DESCRIPTION
    The Start-Transcript cmdlet creates a record of all or part of a Windows PowerShell session in a text file. The transcript includes all command that the user
     types and all output that appears on the console.
    

RELATED LINKS
    Online version: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113408
    Stop-Transcript 

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Start-Transcript -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Start-Transcript -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Start-Transcript -full".
```

Note #1: it only records things written to the main console output stream, not Warning / Error / Debug.

Note #2: if you need to record native console applications, [you'll need a slight workaround](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/workaround-for-start-transcript-on-native-processes/)

Comment: I biffed this too - but Start-Transcript does capture the other streams (except for the progress stream).  It just doesn't capture EXE output unless you use the Out-Default trick that Andy refers to everywhere you use an EXE.