# How to conveniently echo commands run from bash script with a custom prefix when running from Azure Pipelines?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want every command ran from a bash script to be echoed with the custom prefix of `##[command]`. This has a meaning when the script is run from Azure Pipelines.

For example, when running `ls -l` from such a script I would like to see something like this:

```
##[command]ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 2447 Nov 14 23:56 1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 1533 Nov 14 23:56 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 1545 Nov 14 23:56 3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 6918 Nov 14 23:56 4.txt
```

The solution could be something automatic or some kind of a function, which could be invoked like this: `run('ls -l')`.

Using a function means there would be a special step in every build job to ensure this function is defined in the `.bashrc` script, so that subsequent steps could see it. At least, this is what I think, not sure if bash steps load the `.bashrc` script at all.

Anyway, the solution should be applicable to multiple steps in an Azure Pipeline YAML without a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use with `bash`:

`PS4="##[command]"; set -x`

Comment: That works beautifully. The only minor issue is that it does not log redirection. But it is good enough for me.