# What is the idiomatic bash way to echo the executed commands which include pipes and embeded evaluations?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, azure-pipelines

For example, consider the following code (running in an ADO pipeline):

```
PS4="##[command]"; set -euxo pipefail

wget -qO- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg > /dev/null
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list > /dev/null
```

The output it produces is pretty confusing:

```
##[command]gpg --dearmor
##[command]sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
##[command]wget -qO- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg
##[command]sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
##[command]]lsb_release -cs
##[command]echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal main'
```

[image]

Is there a better way to do it while keeping it as unobtrusive as it is now? And what is the deal with the `]` character in `]lsb_release -cs` (line 16) ?

Comment: The "idiomatic" way is `set -v`; `set -x` is for debugging. It would be far better if the script printed what it is doing before executing every command and didn't echo the commands at all, though. Like *Retrieving GPG signature from example.com*, *Adding example repo to /etc/apt/sources.list.d*, etc.

Comment: I did `set -x` because that what I was suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695700/how-to-conveniently-echo-commands-run-from-bash-script-with-a-custom-prefix-when, but your answer is better. Could you provide an answer here (and maybe to that other question) so that I could credit you?

Comment: Nah, post an answer yourself and mark it accepted. Thanks and have a nice day

Comment: @oguzismail - question. Using `set -x` has the benefit of respective the `PS4` prompt - the output it produces is prefixed with `$PS4`. `set -v` ignores `PS4`. I need to output a fixed prefix before each command. Can `set -v` do that?

Comment: No. But `trap 'echo prefix $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG` can. These are all written in the manual