# What is the Powershell equivalent of `set -x` to print each command before execution?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, debugging, scripting

For debugging purposes I would like to easily know which commands are responsible for various parts of the output, I could manage with enough `echo` sprinkled around, but a easily set option would be best.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell "echo on"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063995/powershell-echo-on)

Comment: [How to run a PowerShell script with verbose output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41324882/995714)

Answer (score 13):

As explained in [PowerShell "echo on"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063995/powershell-echo-on) the solution is to run `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1` or `Set-PSDebug -Trace 2` in your script.

Comment: Note that `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1` or `Set-PSDebug -Trace 2` are like Bash's `set -v` option, _not_ like `set -x`, in that the _raw source code line_ of the statement is echoed rather than the statement _with variable references and expressions expanded_.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70020655/45375) tries to provide a - limited - workaround.